# How do I get an array of strings from a powershell pipeline?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a list of directory names that I want to convert to absolute paths, and strip out any invalid ones. My initial attempt at doing this was the pipeline

```
$dirs = 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'
$paths = $dirs | % { Resolve-Path -ea 0 $_ } | Select -ExpandProperty Path
```

However, what I get back has type `[Object[]]` rather than `[String[]]`. I tried ensuring that the paths existed (by adding a `? { Test-Path $_ }` step to the pipeline, but that didn't help.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the directories as a list of strings? I need this so that I can concatenate the array to another array of strings, specifically

```
$newpath = (($env:PATH -split ';'), $paths) -join ';'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object[]` is simply the default array in PowerShell, and it doesn't matter in this (and most) situations. You problem is that you're trying to join to arrays using `(arr1, arr2)`. What this acutally does is create an array with two array objects, because `,` is an array construction operator. Try to join the arrays using `+`, like this:

```
$dirs = 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'
$paths = $dirs | % { Resolve-Path -ea 0 $_ } | Select -ExpandProperty Path    

$newpath = (($env:PATH -split ';') + $paths) -join ';'
```

and you could even skip the splitting, and just do

```
$dirs = 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'
$paths = $dirs | % { Resolve-Path -ea 0 $_ } | Select -ExpandProperty Path
$newpath = "$env:PATH;$($paths -join ';')"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
 $newpath = (@($env:PATH) + $paths) -join ';'
```

You don't really need to explicitly cast it as [string[]].  Powershell will figure that out from the command context and coerce the data to the proper type.